# Access denied when trying to get my MailboxSettings using Select with MailboxSettings.Read

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I am trying to get MailboxSettings of the currently logged in user ("/me") using the .net graph client.

I have a working solution, using an extension method that uses "/me/mailboxSettings", but I have found out that extension methods are not easy to test, though possible, and would prefer a solution that works without one.

I have found out that using `Me.Request().Select("MailboxSettings")` should work as well but I get a service exception with "Access denied" using the same authentication, which has these permissions : "(...) MailboxSettings.Read User.Read User.ReadBasic.All"

Testing with the graph explorer shows that the request does generally work, though I am not sure if this is because it has more permissions as our app on azure - specfically MailboxSettings.ReadWrite, but I would not know why these should be required on a Get method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that MailboxSettings.Read did not work for me.  I needed to consent to MailboxSettings.ReadWrite before I could actually read the settings.  Could you try that and confirm if that works for you?

Comment: I thought I checked that already, but I will do it again more thoroughly - once I am at work.

Comment: Okay, it seems that, for whatever reason, it needs ReadWrite, even though it is a GET operation. Guess I have to continue to use the "me/mailboxSettings" path through an extension method for now.

Comment: @Beliar Thanks for confirming.  We are investigating why this is.

Comment: I also have the same problem. I need to get the timezone settings and have only MailboxSettings.Read. It works only for some accounts and the concent screen is broken for all personal accounts.
Will this be fixed?

Comment: @D.Gencheva  Interesting to know that it works for some accounts?  Do have any idea what the difference is between accounts that work and ones that don't?  You could add a request to the new UserVoice to try and get this addressed https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com